# Why jsonb-functions does not work on update when column is null?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a `jsonb` column, where the column default value is `null`. Now when I try to update this column with data first time using `jsonb_set` or `jsonb_insert` I get `UPDATE 1` as a result but actually, the column stays `null`.

I made little test-case:

```
CREATE SCHEMA test;
CREATE TABLE test.books (  
  book_id serial NOT NULL,
  data jsonb
);

INSERT INTO test.books (data) VALUES (null);
INSERT INTO test.books (data) VALUES ('{}');
```

Now I update both new records:

```
UPDATE test.books SET data = jsonb_set( data, '{zzz}', 'true', true) WHERE book_id = 1;
UPDATE test.books SET data = jsonb_set( data, '{zzz}', 'true', true) WHERE book_id = 2;
```

And result:

```
# select * from test.books;
 book_id |                data                
---------+------------------------------------
       2 | {"zzz": true}
       1 | 
(2 rows)
```

Even when the update yielded the same result for both updates, the first row remained untouched.

I looked into documentation but found nothing about such behavior. Why it does not work this way?

I am using Postgres 9.6

Comment: There was [a lengthy discussion](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAAOiGNwUsgM-UBqsJH_mriCFr-JCPxD%2BpQoXNvyOEQPc%2BYHQRQ%40mail.gmail.com) on pgsql-hackers about this. In the end it was decided to [add `jsonb_set_lax` in v13](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=a83586b5543b948f9e621462537a7303b113c482).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `jsonb_set()` is defined as `strict` which means if any input parameter is `null` the result is null.

You will need to use `coalesce()` in your call to jsonb_set:

```
UPDATE books 
   SET data = jsonb_set( coalesce(data, '{}'), '{zzz}', 'true', true) 
WHERE book_id = 1;
```

Note that this is true for *any* of the parameters of the function.
So `jsonb_set(data, '{zzz}', null, true)` would also yield `null` even if `data` is not null.

Comment: Very clear, `data` as first parameter is `NULL`. You shoot such cases from the hip ;)

Comment: @w.k: I stumbled over that as well. But in the end it's the same behaviour as e.g. `some_text_column || 'add this'` - the result will be `null` if `some_text_column` is null

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me to set a native JSON value of *null* within a JSONB variable was the following:

```sql
IF condition = 1 THEN
    response = jsonb_set(
                    jsonb_in => response::jsonb,
                    path => ('{response, data, my_key')::text[],
                    replacement => 'null'::jsonb,
                    create_if_missing => true
                );
END IF;
```